# Exception 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in DirectWriteForwarder.dll

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

I am building a WPF app on .NET Core 3.1. Basically, the setup of the app is a main screen with a tab control with two tabs. Each tab has a thread running in the background to pull data from different devices.

In each tab I have a frame that holds a page so that each page opens and closes every time the tab is changed to reduce load on the UI thread.

```xml
<TabControl SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMainTab, Mode=TwoWay}">

    <!-- SCAN TAB -->
    <TabItem x:Name="ScanTab">
        <TabItem.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TabTextBlock}" Text="Scan" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem.Header>
        <Frame Source="ScanView.xaml"/>
    </TabItem>

    <!-- VALIDATION TAB -->
    <TabItem x:Name="ValidationTab">
        <TabItem.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="150" Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TabTextBlock}" Text="Validation" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem.Header>
        <Frame Source="ValidationView.xaml"/>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Basically, when a page unloads, I have it stop the thread that was running, polling the device status. Simple enough. But what happens is when I load up the app and begin switching back and forth between the tabs. The UI freezes up and then it crashes with `An Exception 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in DirectWriteForwarder.dll`

There is no line number that this occurs on and from a bit of googling I can't seem to find much about what this DLL is except it is part of .net. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

Upon trying to replicate the error I also get it to crash with System.Collections.dll being the location the exception occurs. Same exception though.

Answer (score 0):

So I might have an answer to my own question. I did not fully determine the cause of the issue. But figured out it was something to do with garbage collection and probably how I was disposing of one thread when switching tabs.

Ultimately, on the unloading event of the page that is opened by the tab, I placed the "shutdown" functionalities inside a thread with IsBackground = true. This will allow them to dispose of themselves without some properties they use from the page being disposed of.

This has seemed to fix my issue since I do not receive that crash anymore.